# Validate in excel to upload only numeric values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an Excel file in which user uploads numeric values. I want to restrict user if the file has string values, and I only want to allow user to upload `Numeric` values.

This is my code:

```
if (dtExcelRows.Columns[j].ColumnName == "SAP_ID")
{
    if (Convert.ToString(dtExcelRows.Rows[i][j]).Trim() != "")
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(dtExcelRows.Rows[i][j]).Length != 18)
        {
            strFlag = strFlag + " " + dtExcelRows.Columns[j].ColumnName + "  length should be equal to 18 characters  |";
            strInvalidSapID = "1";
            strFlagStatus = "No Process";
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (dtExcelRows.Columns[j].ColumnName == "Replacement/New site Net Budget requirement (In Rs/US$)")
{
    if (Convert.ToString(dtExcelRows.Rows[i][j]).Trim() != "")
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(dtExcelRows.Rows[i][j]).Length != "Need to check here")
        {
            strFlag = strFlag + " " + dtExcelRows.Columns[j].ColumnName + "  Only numbers are allowed  |"; // please suggest what to check for numeric
            strInvalidSapID = "1";
            strFlagStatus = "No Process";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the TryParse method for int. If it returns false the value is not a number :

```
bool isNumber = TryParse("YOUR_NUMBER", out int result);
```

EDIT : Just saw there stands "numeric" not number. You can also TryParse for different types(double,float,single,etc).